# How to know which UIView or UIViewController receives a UITouch event or gesture?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

For debugging purposes, is there a way to know which view receives/processes a UITouch or gesture? I am looking for a generic approach rather than having to put NSLog into all UIView or UIViewController classes.

I would like a global generic way to find out which view receives the touch or gesture by outputting its view tag.

Answer (score 0):

Practically speaking, it is the view with focus.  From there the button will invoke a function based on what IBOutlet is wired to fire when the touch event occurs (assuming you are using Interface Builder).  Any IBAction will accept a "sender" and this sender object will allow you to determine the control that actually caused the event to fire.

Answer (score 0):

You could override UIWindow's `sendEvent:`.